# Как открыть ярлык приложения, ведущего на сайт, на рабочем столе?

Tags: ubuntu, ярлыки

в Files открыть приложение получается, но если попытаться открыть на рабочем столе, то оно не реагирует.
Сам ярлык дополнительно поместил в /usr/share/applications/
Как я сделал приложение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее создал линк/ярлык MyChatGPT

здесь не открывается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А уже здесь все спокойно открывается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И даже добавив CgatGPT.desktop (ChatGPT - Изначальное приложение) в /usr/share/applications/ все равно не работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделай десктоп файл. Ссылка это не ярлык, это другое

Comment: "Enable "Allow Launching" - через контекстное меню откройте свойства файла и в правах разрешите запуск. Либо через терминал выполните `chmod +x ChatGPT.desktop`